# Cannot enable MFA on Azure Microsoft accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to enable the Multi-Factor Authentication on my Azure account, (To secure my access to the Azure portal), i am following the tutorial from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-cloud), but, unlike this picture :

[image]

I have no *Enable* button when I select my user:

[image]

I've tried to send a csv bulk request with only my user (the email address), but it says *user does not exists*.

I am trying to add MFA on the user *william@[something].com* when i'm logged with the *william@[something].com* MS account (i am the only one user, and i'm global administrator)

Answer (score 1):

In the MFA management page, you can only manage/enable MFA for your own Microsoft Azure AD Accounts, including accounts creating in Azure AD or synced from your on-premise AD; not any Microsoft Account or accounts from other Microsoft Azure AD. As you said you're using a MS account, you surely can't see the **enable** button.

In [Azure Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), you can easily see if it's a Microsoft account or a Microsoft Azure Active Directory account:

[image]

If you want to enable this for your Microsoft account, you need to use Microsoft service at [here](https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage?mkt=en-us) ,sign in and then click **Set up two-step verification**.
[image]

Follow steps afterwards, you'll enable Two-step Verification it for your Microsoft account.

Of course you can [create a new account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users) in your Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Type of User is: **New user in your organization**), then you can enable MFA for this new user. If you would like a Global Admin, you can click this user and assign user Global Admin role. So then later you can use this admin account for your management work.

Comment: I already have turned on the two step verification here. And the two step shows up when I want to connect to thing url, but is never asked when accessing to the azure portal (tried with Incogognito mode with cache deleted etc.)

Comment: Thank you for feedback, my point here is: Is your account a Microsoft account? If so, you can't enable MFA there as I stated above.

Comment: How can I know? It was created to be used with a Bizspark (msdn, azure, ...) offer.

Comment: Then it might be. I'll add a screenshot in the answer where you can see if it's a Microsoft account.

Comment: The account is definitely a `Microsoft account` and a `Global admin`. So, what can I do? I can secure simple users, but not the most powerfull and important account ?

Comment: I already have turned on the two step verification on the account.live.com link you shared, but the MFA doesn't show up on the azure portal. It shows up only when I connect to account.live.com

Comment: Then you can'e enable MFA for your account in this portal. you need to do it at  https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage?mkt=en-us. This has nothing to do if it's a global admin or not. In your Azure AD, you can create another account (Choose Type of user as: New user in your organization) and assign this user global admin. You'll be able to enable MFA for this user. You can later use this account for your management work. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: The MFA is for your organization account, Microsoft account is not your organization account, this account belongs to Microsoft corp. Create a new user in your own Azure Active Directory, you'll clear. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130231/discussion-between-matthieu-charbonnier-and-frankdong-msft).